# specify the order in which modules load

Tags: .net, prism, mef

I am replacing unity with mef in my prism application.  One of the things I see is that modules are also affected as well.

My IModule classes are now all empty.  How do I specify the order in which the modules load with the MEF bootstrapper?  Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully it doesn't matter. If you have module dependencies, you should specify them with the [ModuleDependency] attribute, but if your modules are empty, I don't see that being a problem. I imagine you are concerned that any exported types might have dependencies, but MEF figures all of that out for you.  No need to worry.